# Why won't Vagrant ssh into my virtual box when I use `Vagrant Up` on Windows 7 command line?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, virtualbox, puppet, vagrant

Whenever I try to Vagrant Up it will load the box and do most everything right, but because I'm trying to use Puppet to provision this CentOS 6.3 minimal I need SSH to work during Vagrant Up (if I want it as autonomous as possible).

I get the following information from Vagrant's INFO log:

```
DEBUG virtualbox_4_2:   - [1, "ssh", 2222, 22]
 INFO ssh: Connecting to SSH: 127.0.0.1:2222
 INFO ssh: SSH not up: #<Timeout::Error: execution expired>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "c2e7375d-159f-4014-9bda-ff9914423f4c", "--machinereadable"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: name="Vagrant-Apache-Nick_1360372174"
```

Comment: Based on the debug info: 1. either NAT port forwarding rule is NOT working or 2. Your host (Windows) is NOT able to connect localhost port 2222 (firewall?). Check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During `Vagrant Up` your Windows system tries to connect to SSH. If you type on your command line:

```
set VAGRANT_LOG=INFO
```

You may see it fail and try a couple of times. It looks like this:

```
INFO ssh: Connecting to SSH: 127.0.0.1:2222
```

This is happening because the timeout is set to 10. This can be modified by placing the following in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.ssh.timeout = 300
```

You can use any number you like but I recommend something above 100.

Sources:

1. [This guy had some useful troubleshooting information.](http://devops.me/2011/10/10/vagrant-tricks-and-troubleshooting/)
2. [Vagrant Docs for Vagrantfiles](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/ssh/timeout.html)
3. [Vagrant Docs for Vagrantfile SSH Timeout](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/ssh/timeout.html)
4. [Vagrant Docs for Debugging](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/debugging.html)
5. [Hours of Troubleshooting (Keep Smilin')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofthf.gif)

Comment: Thank you for the set VAGRANT_LOG=INFO. This is gold!

Comment: Same kind of problem exists with me as well, When I run "vagrant up" command it shows 

 default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222

 default: SSH username: vagrant

 default: SSH auth method: private key

 default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm WAY late to this post, but I did have nearly the exact same problem for a full day before I simply removed Hyper-V from Windows and it magically solved my issue.

I guess when I was testing with Docker for Windows (not to be confused with docker-machine) it goofed my Hyper-V somehow. Not 100% sure why this tweaked fixed this issue, but it worked like a charm after Docker for Windows seemed to fubar my VirtualBox (Docker for Windows and Local by FlyWheel / VirtualBox conflict with each other).

[image]

Hopefully this helps someone out!